# How can I save videos as .MAT files with their names in matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, video

I have a data set of big number of videos so, I want to read these videos and save each video separately with its name because it consumes a lot of time to process among all these videos every time specially for training and classification. If you have any idea how can read all video files in the specified folder D:\words of format .avi and save each one with its own name as .MAT file. 
But this code doesn't work
Thanks,,,

```
       files = fuf('D:\words');
       for i = 1:size(files);
       name = files{i};
       file = strcat('D:\words',name);
       x = VideoReader(file.avi); %NOT SURE FROM THIS LINE%
       v = read(x)
       name = strcat(name,'.mat');
       save(name,'v'); 
       end
```

Comment: "this code doesn't work" is not helpful. What doesn't work? Have you at least tried removing some semicolons and printing out each line? If `file` is a variable containing a file name, why are you not passing that to `VideoReader` (`file.avi` is likely meaningless). What is `fuf`? Is it [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1378-files-under-folders-fuf) perhaps?

Comment: I mean it has errors or it does not achieve the required output. yes, I've tried sir fuf a function called files under folders but this code gives out an error "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an additional function like `fuf` to get a list of file names. 
If all your files are in "D:\words" (i.e. not in a bunch of sub-directories, which would complicate things), you can just use things like `ls` to fetch a list of all the avi files.

This is not the most elegant way of doing it (hard coding the directory and not using things like `fullfile`), but hopefully it's relatively easy to understand what's going on:

```
% use ls or dir to specifically match *.avi files
files = ls('D:\words\*.avi')

% note that size can return more than one value
% hence size(files,1)

for n = 1:size(files,1); 

    filename = files(n,:);  % pick one file

    % assuming this works - you might want to do some error checking
    x = VideoReader(filename);
    v = read(x);

    % now we just want the name minus the ext
    [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(filename);
    fout = ['D:\words\',name,'.mat'];
    save(fout,'v');

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `file` is likely a string, not a structure:

```
...
file = strcat('D:\words',name);
x = VideoReader(file);
...
```

Or maybe this if the files in your cell array don't have extensions:

```
...
file = strcat('D:\words',name);
x = VideoReader([file '.avi']);
...
```

If your `fuf` function returns files that are not AVI movies, you'll need to do more work.

Comment: Please don't !!! yell. And don't post snippets of information that aren't helpful. Take your time. Debug a little by making sure each line prints out what it should. Update your question as I suggested above and provide the full details of the error, including line numbers. Can you even run this code without using `fuf`? I.e., can you hard code the path to the AVI file in a string?